# retryWhen used with flatMap throws exception

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-reactor

I wanted to retry in case of any exception from the service. But when using retryWhen am getting  exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: UnicastProcessor allows only a single Subscriber.

Without retry, its working fine

```
Flux.window(10)
    .flatMap(
          windowedFlux -> 
         webclient.post().uri(url)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(windowedFlux, Request.class))
        .exchange()
        .doOnNext(ordRlsResponse -> {
                     if( ordRlsResponse.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {                               
                        Mono<ResponseEntity<Response>> response = ordRlsResponse.toEntity(Response.class);              
                        //doing some processing here             
                     }           
                     else {                  
                        throw new CustomeException(errmsg);              
                     }

        }).retryWhen(retryStrategy)).subscribe();
```

And my `retryStrategy` is defined like:

```
Retry retryStrategy = Retry.fixedDelay((long)5, Duration.ofSeconds((long)5)) 
                         .filter(exception -> exception instanceof CustomeException) 
                         .doAfterRetry( exception -> log.info("Retry attempted"))
```

Comment: you are somehow returning a UnicastProcessor in your code, so please post more of your code.

Comment: Can you share the `retryStrategy`?

Comment: Retry retryStrategy = Retry.fixedDelay((long)5, Duration.ofSeconds((long)5))
    .filter(exception -> exception instanceof CustomeException)
    .doAfterRetry(
      exception -> log.info("Retry attempted")).

Comment: @Thomas Andolf 
   `Flux.window(10)
    .flatMap(
    windowedFlux -> 
   webclient.post().uri(url)
  .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(windowedFlux, Request.class))
  .exchange()  
  .doOnNext(ordRlsResponse -> {  
  if( ordRlsResponse.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {    
    Mono<ResponseEntity<Response>> response = ordRlsResponse.toEntity(Response.class);
    //doing some processing here
    }
    else {
     throw new CustomeException(errmsg);
    }
  }).retryWhen(retryStrategy)).subscribe();`

Comment: Dont post it here, update your question

Comment: please update your question so that it shows what `doOnNext` returns

Comment: Same with flux.window(...).filter(...).flatMap(...). Internally, some methods produce an UnicastProcessor which is single shot only. In some cases an additional .map(Flux::cache) might be suitable.